# How can I only redirect to USA App store via iTunes URL address?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

Let's say there is an app called, Mega Jump.

This one is available on All country App Store.

here is the iTunes address for USA store.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mega-jump/id370398167?mt=8

If a Canadian clicks this address on iPhone, it redirects to Canadian App Store.

I am sure that Canadians have USA store account too.

Therefore, I would like to force them to USA store via iTunes url link to increase USA sales.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you sure that canadians have a USA store account too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot link to and open a specific storefront for a user.  A user only has one storefront per account.  If the user has more than one account, as you may or may not have assumed correctly, whichever storefront the user has last used is the store a link will attempt to open the content in.

Answer (score 0):

the URL of iTunes normally has the country code in this way:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/be/album/
```

Thus it's sufficeint to preform the URL on that way and you are safe.
You can also use the URL without the country code after the domain, and adding it  as argument by writing `&cc=it` for italy or `&cc=gb` for UK etc, for instance

```
https://itunes.apple.com/be/album/...../id......&cc=it
```

on purpose I put the dots instead of the title of the song and the figures of th song ID to avoid advertising